# Automated email sending

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, automation, landing-page

I have a landing page in salesforce which has its own form and using ampscript i am storing data in dataextension .Now the data that is being send contains two email address and i want to send an email to those address when the data is submitted.Is there any way to automate this in sfmc.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a Smart Capture form in your landing page, you can use the CloudPage Entry source in Journey Builder to send transactionnal emails after form submition.

Otherwise, you can use an Entry Event based Journey for your emails and add an HTTP Post API Call to your Landing Page AMPScript with the collected data.

- CloudPage Entry Source documentation : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_use_cloudpages_to_admit_contacts.htm&type=5
- HTTP Post using AMPScript : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/httppost.htm

Comment: I havent used smart capture .So, can i add the field values from form as contacts in journey builder .If so any documenntation would be helpful.Thanks

Comment: Yes, you just need to link the information to a ContactKey that would be used for the journey flow.